# Understanding MongoDB geo bits resolution

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

The GeoSpatial [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/) states that the default 26 bits yields about 1 foot of spatial resolution. This is about correct if we consider 2 ^ 26 / 6371 km.

However, 6371 is the radius of the earth, not the circumference, which is 40075 km. 26 bits would result in a resolution of 59.7 cm (1.96').

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I flagged this  for close because its a bug report more than anything else. It should have been asked on the google groups or in a jira ticket.

Comment: @JustinDearing It wasn't intended as a bug report, but happened to end up as one. It was intended as it is stated.

Comment: @georgestocker this question resulted in a bug in the documentation being fixed. How is this "not a real question"?

Comment: @IanC This is a question for the people who write the docs, not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, I've fixed the docs to say "approximately 2 feet."